# Alterar escala do eixo y para mostrar diferenças decimais em um gráfico de barras

Tags: r, barplot

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Estou plotando um grafico de barras, as diferenças entre as barras são de 0,1 como faço para mexer no eixo de forma que essas diferenças apareçam ?

```
fvcmt = c(95.2, 95.3, 95.4, 95.1, 95.1, 94.8, 95.1)

fevmt = c(91.9, 92.1, 92.3, 91,4, 91.8, 90.1, 91.8)

a =c("18 to 23", "24 to 29", "30 to 35", "36 to 41", "42 to 47", "48 to 53", 
  "54 to 59")

barplot(fvcmt, width = 50, ylim = c(0, 100), 
  ylab = c("FVC Pereira et al/ FVC Moldel"),
  main = 'Males', axes =F, names.arg = a, xlab = "Ages")

axis(2, at = seq(0,150, by = .5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine os limites do eixo y com o argumento `ylim` dentro da função `barplot`. No caso, eu defini que o eixo deveria ir do mínimo de `fvcmt` até o máximo de `fvcmt`, respectivamente subtraindo e adicionando 1 unidade a estes valores, para deixar o gráfico respirar um pouco.

Entretanto, se não utilizar o `xpd = FALSE` na hora de fazer o gráfico de barras, elas não vão ficar dentro da janela gráfica. Portanto, o código final fica assim, já com os ticks do eixo y definidos de modo a não ficarem um por cima do outro:

```
fvcmt = c(95.2, 95.3, 95.4, 95.1, 95.1, 94.8, 95.1)

fevmt = c(91.9, 92.1, 92.3, 91,4, 91.8, 90.1, 91.8)

a =c("18 to 23", "24 to 29", "30 to 35", "36 to 41", "42 to 47", "48 to 53", 
     "54 to 59")

par(cex = 0.9)
barplot(fvcmt, width = 50, ylim = c(min(fvcmt)-1, max(fvcmt)+1), 
        ylab = c("FVC Pereira et al/ FVC Moldel"),
        main = 'Males', axes =F, names.arg = a, xlab = "Ages",
        xpd = FALSE)

axis(2, at = seq(floor(min(fvcmt)-1), ceiling(max(fvcmt)+1), by = .5))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Grata pela ajuda